# PHP not rendering HTML in emails

Tags: php, drupal

I have a Drupal web app that sends out emails when orders are placed. We have HTMLMail in place to format outgoing messages with a theme. Currently the header and footer are wrapped correctly as they should be with graphics, but the body text is showing raw HTML code.

Example:

```
<p>We have received your order and one of our representatives will review your information shortly. If you have any questions about this order please call us at (phone). Please reference your reservation number when calling. Here are the details of your order:</p><div class="item-list"><h3>Order Summary</h3><ul><li class="first"><span class="confirmation-label">Confirmation Number:</span>
```

And so on and so forth. In the mail template, simply doing an 'echo $body;' to print the message which should contain the above.

Comment: Not familiar with HTMLMail module but... is it possible that  the body may have the wrong text format filter applied?

Answer (score 1):

Set the the body's content type to `text/html` and make sure that you don't have any code automatically escaping it.